# Problem with Date field after migration from mysql to oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, jira

I have lately migrate my JIRA database from mysql to oracle, 
my problem is the field "created" exists in the jiraissue and changegroup tables,on this field I effectuate many calculation  but I was surprised by the difference of the format of the fields.

in mysql database the field creation has the type timeStamp so it has the follwing format:

[image]

and in Oracle database it has the type date and the format like the following:

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of your displayed Oracle DATE column is due to your IDE that you are viewing it through.

Oracle stores all portions of a date, to display the full date stored use this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(created, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  FROM jiraissue;
```

This will show you the full date that has been stored including the time portion. To store timestamps you need the column to be designated as a timestamp datatype column.

Ollie.

EDIT: You could change the NLS Date Format of your IDE to always show the full date format in it's settings somewhere.

Comment: As per Tony's comment, if you want the date displayed in exactly the same format as your MySQL dates then use the format mask he supplied, otherwise there are many Oracle data formats as described here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210

Answer (score 1):

Dates are not held as formatted text in Oracle.  What you are seeing is a tool's (Toad's?) default formatting of the date to display it to you.  This can be changed via a preference somewhere.  It could be that the time component has been lost in migration, but that is unlikely.  Try running this SQL to see:

```
select to_char (created, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from jiraissue;
```

That should show the dates just as they appeared in MySQL.